# Factor not factoring quadratic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

I'm using version 11.3

```
Expand[(Sqrt[2] - t)^2]
2 - 2 Sqrt[2] t + t^2,
```

but

```
Factor[2 - 2 Sqrt[2] t + t^2]
2 - 2 Sqrt[2] t + t^2.
```

On the other hand, without the $\sqrt{2}$ the expression is factored as expected.

```
Factor[1 - 2  t + t^2]
(-1 + t)^2
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting a new question. See the tag description for why.

Answer (score 7):

If you want irrational coefficients, you need to tell it which numbers to use as an extension of the rationals.

```
Factor[2 - 2 Sqrt[2] t + t^2, Extension -> {Sqrt[2]}]
(* (Sqrt[2] - t)^2 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know what extension to use with [`Factor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html)

```
expr = 2 - 2 Sqrt[2] t + t^2;
expr2 = (a + b*t)^2;

sol = expr2 /. Solve[Thread[CoefficientList[expr, t] ==
     CoefficientList[expr2, t]], {a, b}]

(* {(-Sqrt[2] + t)^2, (Sqrt[2] - t)^2} *)

expr == sol // Thread // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```